# Inherit transform-value from other state

Tags: css, css-transforms

I've got an image which will scale on hover. However, at the same time the image get's translated to -50% on both the X and Y axis, or in some cases, only on the X axis.

Is there a way to inherit the previous transform while still changing one of the values?

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 640px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1);
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%) scale(1);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transition: 500ms;
}

img.special {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) scale(1);
  transform: translateX(-50%) scale(1);
  top: 0;
}

img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.1);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/640/400/nature" alt="test image" />
</div>
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/640/400/abstract" class="special" alt="test image" />
</div>
```

**TL:DR;**
Is there a way to inherit the original transform settings, while still changing one of the values?
I'm **not** looking for answers adding extra css, classes or whatever. I'm just looking for a way to keep this as short as possible. I've already solved this using extra classes and CSS.

Comment: Nope, there is no way to inherit and append. One option that you could use is to apply one transform on the child (the `scale`) and the translate on a dummy container (not your existing `.container`).

Comment: @Harry, Thanks, I was afraid of that. Thank you for your reply though.

Comment: Are you expecting the "no" to be posted as an answer? Just curious as you've left the question open :)

Comment: Fair question. I guess I was just hoping for someone to come with a genius solution or anything. But I might as well close it since it won't be coming ;-)

Comment: You can always answer it with the alternative. Should anyone ever be looking for the same thing, they might find help in it :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there a way to inherit the original transform settings, while still changing one of the values?

No, there is no way to do this in CSS. CSS `transform` property declarations (like all other properties) are not additive. The latest setting (or) the one which is more specific will completely override anything else specified and hence there is no chance to *inherit* some values and add on top of it.

The only alternative with pure CSS is to add an extra wrapper and apply one of the transforms to it. In this way, the `img:hover` styling (the `scale`) need not be repeated and can be left as common for all.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  height: 400px;
  width: 640px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
}
.special.wrapper {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  top: 0;
}
.wrapper img {
  transition: 500ms;
}
img:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/640/400/nature" alt="test image" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper special">
    <img src="http://www.lorempixel.com/640/400/people" alt="test image" />
  </div>
</div>
```

The other way would be to use JavaScript, find out what is the current transform on the element, then append the extra transform on hover and apply it via inline styles.